# Is there a forward delete on the iPad?

Tags: ipad

Using the screen keyboard on iPad, is their a way to delete the character after the cursor?  That is, behavior like the Windows delete key?

I am aware that the convention is to use Fn+delete on Macs.  If there is no such convention on iPad, it might be nice to use shift+delete.

Comment: On Mac, one can also use control + D for this purpose.

Comment: @Mahnax Ooo...very cool little shortcut! I need to remember that one!

Comment: @daviesgeek Yeah, I actually discovered it by accident once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, but no.  This only works on the iPad if you are using an external Bluetooth keyboard.

Answer (score 3):

Yes I found it! it is control + K.

You can find additional iPad shortcuts on the web, e.g. https://www.tomsguide.com/us/ipad-shortcuts,news-18205.html

Answer (score 0):

The app [Textkraft](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/textkraft/id470843464?mt=8) has a forward-delete key.

Comment: You should provide a link to the app, at least, and mention what sort of app it is.